# inserting superclass in rails, without corresponding database table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to have a common superclass for two models in ruby, to share several methods. Let's say I want a `Truck` and `Car` inheriting from `Vehicle`. Here are some options:

1. Make `class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base`, and have `class Truck < Vehicle` etc. But then I get errors saying I don't have a table for `Vehicle` (and I don't want one, either).
2. Use `module Vehicle` and `include Vehicle` in `class Truck < ActiveRecord::Base`. But then `attr_reader` and friends don't get applied to `Truck`.

Thus, I want `class Vehicle`. How do I do this without requiring a table? I'm sure there's a standard, nice way of doing this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a **class** method called `abstract_class?` that returns `true`:

```
class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.abstract_class?
    true
  end
end
```

Comment: Ah, perfect, I knew this had to have a clean solution. Thanks!